# Can't load image from svg on React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

### The Issue

I was working to load image from svg(Scalable Vector Graphics) file on React. I tried a few solution ways and I didn't received any result. Those are solutions that have been tried:

#### Solution - 1

```html
<img src="../../assets/icons/branch.svg" alt="branch" />
```

Firstly, I was reading many articles and seen this way: Directly set source to svg. But that didn't work.

#### Solution - 2

```html
<i className="branch">:</i>
```

```css
.branch {
  background-image: url('../../assets/icons/branch.svg');
}
```

Secondly, I tried use to background image and that didn't work.

#### Solution - 3

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="../../assets/icons/branch.svg" aria-label="branch">
  Image
</object>
```

Thirdly, I tried use to object and that didn't work.

#### Solution 4

When i was trying to use as an in-line svg, it works. But i don't like it, i wanna use that svg as external.

#### Finally

I tried those ways and only in-line way works. Can someone help me to use that svg as external?

Comment: have you tried this: <img src="/assets/icons/branch.svg" alt="branch" />

Comment: @Astros , yes but didn't work. Just shown alt title.

Comment: Check the assets folder if it is in public folder or not?

Comment: @KishoriTutorials, I checked them. Svg file isn't in public folder. It is in src/assets/icons folder.

Comment: Keep the assets folder in public folder and then try the path

Comment: you can do this, on top of your file, import image from `your path`; then in your img src just put `image`. like this `<img src={image} />`

Comment: you can keep in public folder or you can import or you can give relative path  url like-<img src="https://foldername/filename" alt="branch" />

Comment: I agree with @buzz

Comment: @KishoriTutorials, I tried this way now but it didn't work.

Comment: @buzz, That way has been tried but it didn't work.

Comment: @bgebes did you try importing it first and use it the way I showed?

Comment: @buzz, yep. As a sample, `import Img from '../../assets/icons/branch.svg' <img src={Img}>`. But this didn't work.

Comment: As a note, I'm performing this operations on Firefox on Ubuntu 20.04. Maybe, that can effect performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also try this

`import { ReactComponent as Branch } from "../../assets/icons/branch.svg";`

and then use it like

`<Branch/>`

or

`import Branch from "../../assets/icons/branch.svg";`

`background-image: url(${Branch});`

Answer (score 0):

```js
import SvgImg from '{path_to_svg}';`
```

```html
<img src={SvgImg} />
```